# How to change the "GNU GRUB version x.xx" Title

Tags: kali-linux, grub2

I modified my grub menu and I am almost satisfied with it right now.[image]

I used Rufus to put Kali Linux on my USB, then I made EFI/Boot in the root of the drive so that I can boot using UEFI. Is there any way to edit the **GNU GRUB version 2.00** text at the top? I tried to look for etc/default/grub and etc/grub.d but it does not exist because it is Kali Live made with Rufus.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* edit the grub executable and replace the title with a string of the same length.  A feature of ELF format is that there's no checksum.

On my Debian 7, that's (found using `grep -l 'GNU GRUB'`) in `/boot/grub/normal.mod`, which `od` shows uses a nul-terminated string:

```
           726f    616d    206c    6e65    6976    6f72    6d6e    6e65
0153140   t  \0   >  \0   g   r   u   b   >  \0   G   N   U       G   R
           0074    003e    7267    6275    003e    4e47    2055    5247
0153160   U   B           v   e   r   s   i   o   n       %   s  \0   1
```

The `file` command tells you about the format, e.g.,

```
$ file /boot/grub/normal.mod
/boot/grub/normal.mod: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Of course, you should use a suitable tool for this, such as a hex-editor.

Further reading:

- [Fixing the checksum of a modified Android ELF](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/fixing-the-checksum-of-a-modified-android-elf)
- [Is there a way to detect an ELF binary is broken/tampered or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641559/is-there-a-way-to-detect-an-elf-binary-is-broken-tampered-or-not)

Comment: I found the grubx64.efi in `/EFI/Boot`

there are 5 files inside the .efi file, ".data", ".reloc", ".text", "CERTIFICATE",  "mods". Is there anyway to save changes to any edits made in these files? I found a line that says "GNU GRUB  version %s.2.00" in the "mods" file.

Comment: If it's "ELF", it's possible to modify it (with due care).

Comment: When I try to make edits through 7-Zip it says Can not update file, Read-only F:\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi\

Comment: That's a problem for two reasons: the tool may not be a hex-editor, and you have to change the permissions of the file to modify it.  (You should start by making a **copy** of the unmodified file).   By the way, it sounds as if 7-zip is showing you the sections of the ELF file...

Comment: In my live USB I have a folder called `EFI` which contains the folder `Boot` and inside that there is `grubx64.efi` , `BOOTX64.efi` and `grub.cfg` I guess the `grubx64.efi` is the executable grub so I opened it with 7-Zip in windows. Also in windows it shows that `grubx64.efi` and `mods` is not read-only so I should be able to edit it but it doesn't let me.

Comment: Sounds like the windows *system* attribute (see [attrib](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx)).

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to install Ubuntu on another drive and do the main.c tweaks and then replace it on my live USB. Thanks for all the help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to edit the title text is to modify the source code of Grub 2 and recompile, since the title text is hardcoded in `grub-core/normal/main.c` in the source tree.  See [this answer over at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357186/how-to-change-the-header-title-and-help-message-in-grub-menu/361185#361185) for the gritty details - there is too much to reproduce here.

Comment: can I install Ubuntu and copy over the grub files over into my live USB drive?

Comment: Sure, if you want, but if you don't build the grub package on the target platform, you're running the risk that the package won't work when installed on the target platform. Or even worse, that it will appear to work, but actually have subtle bugs.

Comment: what exactly would I have to copy over though?